# Los hilos no funcionan en android

Tags: android

estoy haciendo una app que vaya aumetando los segundos, posteriormete agregare otra funciones, pero por el momento, me marca un error al momento de que los hilos empiezan a funcionar me marca este error.

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Y mi codigo es el siguiente

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
int seg=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reloj);
}
boolean on=false;
public void inicia(View view){
    if(!on){
        tiempo.start();
        on=true;
    }

}

Thread tiempo=new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                seg++;
                tv.setText(seg+"");
            }

        }catch (InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Te he agregado una pequeña implementación haciendo uso de `AsynTask` como te proponía @Sergio Martín Vílchez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo el hilo principal puede modificar la interfaz de usuario (UI), por lo que debes hacer uso de `runOnUiThread` para modificar cualquier vista:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Puedes modificar fácilmente tu código para que haga lo que deseas:

```
Thread tiempo = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        seg++;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run(){  
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(seg));
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
};
```

---

Edición para completar la solución con `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate`:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

Tal y como @Sergio Martín Vílchez ha sugerido, también se puede hacer con `AsyncTask`, aunque yo prefiero la solución anterior:

```
/* Parámetros de entrada (Void), progreso (Integer) y salida (Void) */
new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while(true) {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       publishProgress(seg++);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progreso) {
    /* Esto se ejecuta en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (UI) */
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(progreso[0]));
    /* También podría haberse usado directamente:
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(seg));*/
  }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a usar AsynTask:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Te facilitará mucho las tareas que necesiten correr en segundo plano.